# How to build Binding class in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.android, nuget

I am trying to create a Binding class in Visual Studio like in Android Studio https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding

What I have:

Visual Studio 2022 17.4.5

Xamarin 17.4

What I've done:

1. Create Android App (Xamarin) project. Blank App and minimum android version 10.0
2. install Xamarin.AndroidX.DataBinding.ViewBinding 7.4.0.1 nuget package
3. Adds to the .csproj file

```
<AutoGenerateLayoutBindings>true</AutoGenerateLayoutBindings>
```

4. Adds a  root element to activity_main.xml

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hello_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, world!"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

4. Build project. In output window

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: App4, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Restored C:\Users\koly8\source\repos\App4\App4.csproj (in 73 ms).
1>  App4 -> C:\Users\koly8\source\repos\App4\bin\Debug\App4.dll
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

nothing have been created

Maybe missed something

Comment: Could you provide some more relevant code so that I can reproduce the situation you described?

Comment: source of code https://bitbucket.org/koly86/xamarinvb/src/master/

Comment: Are you sure this feature even exists for Xamarin? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you provided but failed, then refer to the doc: [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start). It said:

> To configure your app to use data binding, enable the `dataBinding` build option in your `build.gradle` file in the app module, as shown in the following example:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

The dataBinding library is actually part of the gradle build toolkit so isn't available in Xamarin.Android applications. For xamarin android the most recommended way is to use data binding is to use the native libraries, for example [MVVMCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross).